# nginx with codeigniter and phpmyadmin

Tags: nginx

After much study / struggle, I was able to configure nginx for codeigniter. I need to clear one last hurdle with phpmyadmin to reach level 4 of nginx config game.

Here's the nginx.conf for my website:

```
  location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @codeigniter;
    }

    location @codeigniter {
            rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fastcgi/php-fastcgi.socket;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/example.com/html/index.php;
    }
```

A bit of explanation: I am using nginx as replacement for apache. I have a symlink to phpmyadmin under /var/www/example.com/html/ folder. Codeigniter requires that SCRIPT_FILENAME point to codeigniter's index.php. Since all php requests are routed through codeiginiter, the try_files fails for phymyadmin. How do I overcome this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is mine, and works just fine:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name testsite.com;

    index index.html index.php;

    root /var/www/com.testsite/public;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @codeigniter;
    }

    location @codeigniter {
            rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?$1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php($|/) {
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                    return 404;
            }
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9001;

            fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
            fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

            fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
            fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
            fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

            fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

            fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
            fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
            fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for helping me reach level 4 of nginx config